# batch file to search all .txt files in folder for string then copy 1st instance to output file.txt

Tags: batch-file, copy, findstr

I have about 100 plus .txt files with long file names in a folder, and I need to search the files for the 1st instance of the string "4096" and return the whole line from each file and copy it to an output .txt file.

I am a novice at batch syntax so a whole solution would be awesome,

thanks in advance.

Comment: what if `4096` is embedded within a larger number? for example `32409671`. Or the number may appear in multiple contexts. I suspect you may need to refine your requirements.

Comment: The answer did help you? then you should mark it as the accepted

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   set found=false
   for /f "skip=2 tokens=*" %%b in ('find "4096" "%%a"') do (
      if "!found!"=="false" (
         echo %%b >>output.txt
         set found=true
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: This help a lot, i just removed the `if` inside the `for` loop and use `copy %%a d:\another_location` and works like a charm. Useful for copy files that contain certain string.